# failure of installing RTextTools

Tags: r

I downloaded the latest R version of R-2.15.0 and install it on Linux. Everything works just fine. But it just fails for installing RTextTools, the error message is

> > install.packages("RTextTools")
> >     Installing package(s) into ‘/home/user/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/2.14’
> >     (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
> >
> > Warning: dependency ‘Rstem’ is not available
> >     trying URL 'http://cran.wustl.edu/src/contrib/RTextTools_1.3.6.tar.gz'
> >     Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 399988 bytes (390 Kb)
>
> opened URL
>
> ERROR: dependency ‘Rstem’ is not available for package ‘RTextTools’
>   * removing ‘/home/user/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/2.14/RTextTools’
>
> The downloaded packages are in
>           ‘/tmp/Rtmp0i44JP/downloaded_packages’
>
> Warning message:
>   In install.packages("RTextTools") :
>     installation of package ‘RTextTools’ had non-zero exit status

How to solve this issue? Thanks

Comment: I googled and `Rstem` is on omegahat so I installed with   install.packages("Rstem", repos = `"http://www.omegahat.org/R"`)
. Then I tried to install `RTextTools` and it made a new error message asking me to reinstall `bitops`. So I did that and tried again to reinstall `RTextTools` and it complained about `caTools` so I reinstalled that... finally `RTextTools` installed successfully. whew.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain you're using 2.15?

Answer (score 0):

Rstem was removed from the CRAN repository several months back, which is why you're getting this error. However, RTextTools was updated to include the stemmers in the source code, and this shouldn't be an installation issue anymore.

Comment: Then how do you explain OP's error then? Is he/she using an outdated CRAN server?

Comment: Seeing as this post was from April 3, it's likely they tried to install RTextTools during the period where Rstem was removed but the update for RTextTools had not yet been released.